# JOIN ON condition with common columns as concatenation of fields

Tags: sql, join, concatenation, field, multiple-columns

I would like to make a JOIN ON but I have no common columns.

The only relationship I have is a column in table B with a concatenation of 2 columns in table A:

Table A:

| id | name | surename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | McKlein |
| 2 | Mark | Johnson |

Table B:

| completeName | sonName |
| --- | --- |
| Joe McKlein | Mike |
| Joe McKlein | Richard |
| Mark Johnson | Peter |
| Joe McKlein | Patrick |

I would like to get:

| id | completeName | sonName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe McKlein | Mike |
| 1 | Joe McKlein | Richard |
| 2 | Mark Johnson | Peter |
| 1 | Joe McKlein | Patrick |

I thought in something like:

```
SELECT a.id, b.completeName, b.sonName FROM tableA AS a JOIN tableB AS b ON b.completeName = CONCAT(a.name, ' ', a.surename)
```

but in 'real tables' with lots of registers (no this ones in the example) I get a 'time expiring error'. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to add a foreign key in your table B that refers to table A

Comment: This method is an anti-pattern and will prevent eficient index usage forcing a scan of all rows. Add a calculated column for the contatenated columns and index it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, adding calculated column and index it should be the perfect solution but the company I am working for doesn't allow me to do it (for now) because it could affect other parts of the application. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I presume by "lots of registers" you perhaps mean lots of *rows* - you have no alternative then other than to accept poor performance since your existing join predicate is not sargable. And note the current proposed answer will have exactly the same issue and likely perform even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The slow performance is due to the bad database design, and nothing you do with your query can speed things up.

The fact that you're getting a 'timeout' makes me wonder if you're writing the query through a 3rd party tool that has a specific timeout. If that's the case, you might be able to change the timeout settings yourself in whatever tool you're using, to basically wait until the query finishes.

If the database server is actually timing out, that could be a user setting that the admins can increase for you. They might not be interested in fixing the table to add the proper foreign keys, but if you are annoying enough, they might just simply increase the timeout or increase the performance profile of your user account so this query can finish before the timeout.

Good luck!

P.S. One tip that might help you do ugly joins like this, is force `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` on both sides of the join to prevent case sensitivity from giving you a mismatch when there is a mistake in capitalization. This won't speed things up, but is just a tip for making this type of join more accurate.